# Python : My programm refuse to work if i replace if statment by elif

Tags: python, if-statement, indentation

I am preparing for my second year of university and on one of the exercises we are asked to do I have several problems related to an if statement

We have to program a Todo app and at one point an exercise asks us to replace the if statement for "show", "edit", "exit", and "completed" by `elif`

The problem is that my program doesn't work at all when I try to replace the original if statement by `elif`

The code before the implementation of the elif statement

```
prompt = " Add or show  or type exit to quit the programm  or edit to edit a item in your list  : "
list = []

while True:
    useraction = input(prompt + " you can also right  completed to remove an task that you have done ")
    useraction = useraction.strip()
    if "add" in useraction:
        todo = useraction[4:]
        with open("app.txt", "r") as file:
            list = file.readlines()

        list.append(todo)
        with open("app.txt", "w") as file:
            file.writelines(list)

    elif "completed" in useraction:
        num = int(input("Please right the number of the task that is completed"))
        with open("app.txt", "r") as file:
            list = file.readlines()
        list.pop(num - 1)

    print("That task has been completed, congratulation!")

    if "show" in useraction:
        with open("app.txt", "r") as file:
            list = file.readlines()

        for index, item in enumerate(list):
            item = item.strip("\n")
            row = f"{index + 1}-{item}"
            row = row.title()
            print(row)

    if "exit" in useraction:
        break

    if "edit" in useraction:
        number = int(input("please right the number of the item that you want to modify : "))
        number = number - 1

        with open("app.txt", "r") as file:
            list = file.readlines()
        new_todo = input("please right the new thing that you want to do : ")
        list[number] = new_todo
    with open("app.txt", "w") as file:
        file.writelines(list)

print("Bye !")
```

When I decide to put the elif statement in the code this is what happens:

```
prompt = " Add or show  or type exit to quit the program  or edit to edit a item in your list  : "
list = []

while True:
    useraction = input(prompt + " you can also right  completed to remove an task that you have done ")
    useraction = useraction.strip()
    if "add" in useraction:
        todo = useraction[4:]
        with open("app.txt", "r") as file:
            list = file.readlines()

        list.append(todo)
        with open("app.txt", "w") as file:
            file.writelines(list)

    elif "completed" in useraction:
        num = int(input("Please right the number of the task that is completed"))
        with open("app.txt", "r") as file:
            list = file.readlines()
        list.pop(num - 1)

    print("That task has been completed, congratulation!")

    elif "show" in useraction:
        with open("app.txt", "r") as file:
            list = file.readlines()

        for index, item in enumerate(list):
            item = item.strip("\n")
            row = f"{index + 1}-{item}"
            row = row.title()
            print(row)

    elif "exit" in useraction:
        break

    elif "edit" in useraction:
        number = int(input("please right the number of the item that you want to modify : "))
        number = number - 1

        with open("app.txt", "r") as file:
            list = file.readlines()
        new_todo = input("please right the new thing that you want to do : ")
        list[number] = new_todo
    with open("app.txt", "w") as file:
        file.writelines(list)

print("Bye !")
```

I have more than 16 errors, the majority of which are related to those :

Statement expected, found Py:ELIF_KEYWORD
An illegal target for a variable annotation
Expression expected
etc...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, sorry if the formatting is not really great, this is my first post on StackOverflow
:

I don't really understand where my error is, I've tried changing my indentation but it just seems to add more errors.

Comment: in your second code you have a line `print("That task has been completed, congratulation!")`  that is not inside the elif but outside, so you cannot continue with more elifs after this line since you already put some code outside the conditional. Remove this line or indent it so it stays inside the elif

Comment: Thank you so much, it would have been hard for me to see the error alone.
I'm sorry my code wasn't formatted properly, I'll see how to format it better for my next posts.
Thanks again

Comment: The use of `in` is odd here.  If you typed "show cradd", for example, it would match the "add" branch.  It would be much better to use `useraction.split()` and then compare for equality with the first word.  And, as a side note, you have the word "right" here in two places where you meant to use "write".

Answer (score 0):

keep the tab between if and elif, print can not in outside of elif
you should modify this line，more tab and let it in elif workspace

#### print("That task has been completed, congratulation!")

this is the codes I modified

```
import os
prompt = " Add or show  or type exit to quit the programm  or edit to edit a item in your list  : "
list = []
filepath = r'C:\Users\10696\Desktop\access\6\app.txt'
if not os.path.exists(filepath):
    f = open(filepath, 'w')
    f.close()
while True:
    useraction = input(prompt + " you can also right  completed to remove an task that you have done ")
    useraction = useraction.strip()
    if "add" in useraction:
        todo = useraction[4:]
        with open(filepath, "r") as file:
            list = file.readlines()

        list.append(todo)
        with open(filepath, "w") as file:
            file.writelines(list)

    elif "completed" in useraction:
        num = int(input("Please right the number of the task that is completed"))
        with open(filepath, "r") as file:
            list = file.readlines()
        list.pop(num - 1)

        print("That task has been completed, congratulation!")

    elif "show" in useraction:
        with open("app.txt", "r") as file:
            list = file.readlines()

        for index, item in enumerate(list):
            item = item.strip("\n")
            row = f"{index + 1}-{item}"
            row = row.title()
            print(row)

    elif "exit" in useraction:
        break

    elif "edit" in useraction:
        number = int(input("please right the number of the item that you want to modify : "))
        number = number - 1

        with open("app.txt", "r") as file:
            list = file.readlines()
        new_todo = input("please right the new thing that you want to do : ")
        list[number] = new_todo
    with open("app.txt", "w") as file:
        file.writelines(list)

print("Bye !")
`
```